# How to differentiate between a single click and a double click in Arduino

Tags: arduino

A disabled user has two light sensitive switches in their mouth. Touching one or the other with their tongue is recognized as a click (vcnl.readProximity() > 60500). This code is set to recognize double clicks. Because the sensors are close together, they sometimes get triggered simultaneously. I thought if one only recognized double clicks and the other recognized single clicks this could reduce errors.

But I can't figure out how to recognize single clicks while ignoring double clicks.

Thanks for any ideas...

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "Adafruit_VCNL4010.h"

Adafruit_VCNL4010 vcnl;

const int buttonPin = 2;    
const int ledPin = 13;
int ledState = 0;         
int firstClick = 0;   // the previous reading from the 
  input pin
int secondClick = 0;
int unClick = 0;
unsigned long lastTime = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT); // to trigger switch
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // to turn on LED for testing
  if (! vcnl.begin()) {
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (firstClick == 0 && vcnl.readProximity() > 60500) 
  {
    firstClick = 1;
    lastTime = millis();
  } else if (firstClick == 1 && vcnl.readProximity() < 
    60500) {
    unClick = 1;
  }

  if (unClick == 1 && vcnl.readProximity() > 60500 && 
    millis() - lastTime < 500) {
    secondClick = 1;
    ledState = 1;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    analogWrite(8, 250);
  }

  if (millis() - lastTime > 500) {
    firstClick = 0;
    unClick = 0;
    secondClick = 0;
    ledState = 0;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    analogWrite(8, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny enough, I was making a tutorial the other day and had a similar scenario but with a momentary switch (I was also looking for 500ms spacing between clicks :-)

Anywho, here's my approach. The logic is that you keep checking for clicks non-stop and keep incrementing a "click" variable but on the first click you start the timer and when it reaches 500ms you check how many clicks you have collected and reset everything to zero.

Here it is:

```
unsigned long lastClickTime = 0;
int currentClickValue = 0;
bool click_in_progress = false;

void loop() {

    //we keep checking for clicks, we don't care about the non-click detection (it will be most of the time)
    if(vcnl.readProximity() > 60500){ //it's a click
        if(currentClickValue == 0){
            lastClickTime = millis(); //reset the timer only on the first click
            click_in_progress = true; //we are in the clicking phase
        }
        currentClickValue++ ; // it will start as 1 and will keep incrementing 
    }

    if(click_in_progress == true){
        if(millis() - lastClickTime >= 500){ //now we have passed the 500ms let's check how many clicks happened
            if(currentClickValue > 1){ 
                
               //it's a double or multiple click
                

            }else{

                //has to be at least 1 so it's a single click, it can never be zero

            }

            //reset everything
            currentClickValue = 0;
            click_in_progress = false;
            //no need to waste processor time resetting lastClickTime as it won't be checked until the next click_in_progress = 1 and it will be reset before that anyway

        }
    }
 
}
```

You can expand this to include triple clicks that can give extra functionality, you can run in parallel another check with different logic and make it work like morse code ...---... and suddenly you have an entire extra command set

Hope this helps :-)